# Excel formula to delete data in a cell from a specific character forward

Tags: excel-formula

I have an  Excel spreadsheet with 5,000+ lines.  Each line has a single cell in it which contains a number of words followed by a value in parenthesis followed by more words.  The number of words varies in each cell.

Example:

**North Avenue (123) North Avenue**

**Highland Parks Mall (456) Highland Parks Mall**

I would welcome any help with a formula that can delete everything from and including the first parenthesis on.

Using the examples above, I would like the cell contents to read:

**North Avenue**

**Highland Parks Mall**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I've tried to search the site but am not even sure how to word the search query for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your value is in A1, use this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" (",A1)-1)
```

This also assumes that every instance has the space, paren or else you will get errors when find fails to match.

Comment: Drop the Space altogether. Use *TRIM* to take care of the extra space. Something like `=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1))`

Comment: That would work also and does deal with the generalized whitespace better, but if this data is of a reliable enough format [it appears to be machine generated] then including the whitespace directly in the find is likely to be faster on a large data set.

Comment: Why is using `TRIM` preferable to what @BitBlitz wrote, considering it's the same result with fewer nested functions?

Comment: @RobW It eliminates the error in `FIND` finding `" ("`?

Comment: @L42 I don't see the error unless the data includes multiple spaces, as BitBlitz notes. The results using the OP's samples are exactly the same between both of your methods.

Comment: @RobW - correct - on well formed data the two solutions produce the same result.  On dirty data the TRIM solution will be more likely to produce a good result but at the cost of some extra running time.  Whether that running time is significant will depend on the machine running it and the quantity of data.